# Ansible Molecule Test Error: cannot reload udev rules: exit status 1

Tags: docker, ansible, dockerfile, molecule

I'm trying to set up Ansible molecule for testing roles on different OSes. For example, this role is failing when it gets to the task that installs with `snap install core`:

https://github.com/ProfessorManhattan/Ansible-Role-Snapd

`molecule.yml`:

```
---
dependency:
  name: galaxy
  options:
    role-file: requirements.yml
    requirements-file: requirements.yml
driver:
  name: docker
platforms:
  - name: Ubuntu-20.04
    image: professormanhattan/ansible-molecule-ubuntu2004
    command: /sbin/init
    tmpfs:
      - /run
      - /tmp
    volumes:
      - /sys/fs/cgroup:/sys/fs/cgroup:ro
    privileged: true
    pre_build_image: true
provisioner:
  name: ansible
  connection_options:
    ansible_connection: docker
    ansible_password: ansible
    ansible_ssh_user: ansible
  inventory:
    group_vars:
      all:
        molecule_test: true
  options:
    vvv: true
  playbooks:
    converge: converge.yml
verifier:
  name: ansible
scenario:
  create_sequence:
    - dependency
    - create
    - prepare
  check_sequence:
    - dependency
    - cleanup
    - destroy
    - create
    - prepare
    - converge
    - check
    - destroy
  converge_sequence:
    - dependency
    - create
    - prepare
    - converge
  destroy_sequence:
    - dependency
    - cleanup
    - destroy
  test_sequence:
    - lint
    - dependency
    - cleanup
    - destroy
    - syntax
    - create
    - prepare
    - converge
    - idempotence
    - side_effect
    - verify
    - cleanup
    - destroy
```

`install-Debian.yml`:

```
---
- name: Ensure snapd is installed
  apt:
    name: snapd
    state: present
    update_cache: true

- name: Ensure fuse filesystem is installed
  apt:
    name: fuse
    state: present

- name: Ensure snap is started and enabled on boot
  ansible.builtin.systemd:
    enabled: true
    name: snapd
    state: started

- name: Ensure snap core is installed # This task is failing
  community.general.snap:
    name: core
    state: present
```

The error I receive is:

```
TASK [professormanhattan.snapd : Ensure fuse filesystem is installed] **********
ok: [Ubuntu-20.04]

TASK [professormanhattan.snapd : Ensure snap is started and enabled on boot] ***
changed: [Ubuntu-20.04]

TASK [professormanhattan.snapd : Ensure snap core is installed] ****************
fatal: [Ubuntu-20.04]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "channel": "stable", "classic": false, "cmd": "sh -c \"/usr/bin/snap install core\"", "msg": "Ooops! Snap installation failed while executing 'sh -c \"/usr/bin/snap install core\"', please examine logs and error output for more details.", "rc": 1, "stderr": "error: cannot perform the following tasks:\n- Setup snap \"core\" (10823) security profiles (cannot reload udev rules: exit status 1\nudev output:\nFailed to send reload request: No such file or directory\n)\n", "stderr_lines": ["error: cannot perform the following tasks:", "- Setup snap \"core\" (10823) security profiles (cannot reload udev rules: exit status 1", "udev output:", "Failed to send reload request: No such file or directory", ")"], "stdout": "", "stdout_lines": []}
```

The same is true for all the other operating systems I'm trying to test. Here's a link to the Dockerfile I'm using to build the Ubuntu image:

`Dockerfile`:

```
FROM ubuntu:20.04
LABEL maintainer="help@megabyte.space"

ENV container docker
ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND noninteractive

# Source: https://github.com/ansible/molecule/issues/1104
RUN set -xe \
  && apt-get update \
  && apt-get install -y apt-utils \
  && apt-get upgrade -y \
  && apt-get install -y \
      build-essential \
      libyaml-dev \
      python3-apt \
      python3-dev \
      python3-pip \
      python3-setuptools \
      python3-yaml \
      software-properties-common \
      sudo \
      systemd \
      systemd-sysv \
  && apt-get clean \
  && pip3 install \
      ansible \
      ansible-lint \
      flake8 \
      molecule \
      yamllint \
  && mkdir -p /etc/ansible \
  && echo "[local]\nlocalhost ansible_connection=local" > /etc/ansible/hosts \
  && groupadd -r ansible \
  && useradd -m -g ansible ansible \
  && usermod -aG sudo ansible \
  && sed -i "/^%sudo/s/ALL\$/NOPASSWD:ALL/g" /etc/sudoers

VOLUME ["/sys/fs/cgroup", "/tmp", "/run"]

CMD ["/sbin/init"]
```

Looking for a geerlingguy.

Comment: You should really make the effort to reduce it to a [mre] rather than linking us your role repository and your Dockerfile

Comment: @β.εηοιτ.βε - what files did you need me to copy over from the repository?

Comment: You need to copy everything that make it the most minimal code that can reproduce your issue. So you shouldn't provide us the whole thing but make the effort to reduce it to the least amount of code in order to reproduce it.

Comment: @β.εηοιτ.βε - ok, I did it -- can you not close this issue please?

Comment: You should really take a look at the [mre] page and specifically at what minimal means. I don't see how, for example but that is the most obvious one, the CentOS platform if even remotely linked to your issue on a Ubuntu node.

Comment: @β.εηοιτ.βε thanks for the advice. it makes sense.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/229053/discussion-between-professormanhattan-and---).